# Adwhirl in UIWindow

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Can Any one help me How to integrate Adwhirl in UIWindow instead of adding in in each ViewController,
or please refer any one of the sample code refer to this problem...
Thanx in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Views get added to the window, the window doesn't inherently have anywhere to display anything, I think. As the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWindow_Class/UIWindowClassReference/UIWindowClassReference.html) states:

> The two principal functions of a window are to provide an area for displaying its views and to distribute events to the views.

If you wanted, you could probably instantiate your `adWhirlView` in the app delegate, and then reference it within each view you're presenting. You'd still have to add the `adWhirlView` to each view yourself, but you wouldn't have to create it new each time.